# Angular TypeScript Date.getFullYear() not a function when returning Observable from server

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am attempting to display data like so:

```html
    <a *ngFor="let month of months">
      <div>
        <h4>{{month.name + month.date.getFullYear()}}</h4>
        <p *ngFor="let topic of month.topics">
            <span>{{topic.description}}</span>
            <li *ngFor="let item of topic.items">
                <span>{{item.content}}</span>
            </li>
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
```

This works perfectly well when I use static Month[] data like so:

```
export const MONTHS: Month[] = [
    { id: 0, name: "September ", date: new Date(2020, 9), topics:[{id: 0, description: "I need a new description", items: [{ id: 0, content: "I need a new todo", isDone: false}]}]},
    { id: 1, name: "August ", date: new Date(2020, 8), topics:[{id: 0, description: "I need a second description", items: [{ id: 0, content: "I need a second todo", isDone: false}]}]},
];
```

However, when I attempt to get the Month[] from an in memory server like so:

```
///The database
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const months = [
      { id: 0, name: "September ", date: new Date(2020, 9), topics:[{id: 0, description: "I need a new description", items: [{ id: 0, content: "I need a new todo", isDone: false}]}]},
      { id: 1, name: "August ", date: new Date(2020, 8), topics:[{id: 0, description: "I need a second description", items: [{ id: 0, content: "I need a second todo", isDone: false}]}]},
    ];
    return {months};
  }
}

///The month.service
/** GET months from the server */
  getMonths(): Observable<Month[]> {
    return this.http.get<Month[]>(this.monthsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched months')),
        catchError(this.handleError<Month[]>('getMonths', []))
      );
  }

///the .ts component of the html display
export class CurrentMonthComponent implements OnInit {
  months: Month[];

  constructor(private monthService: MonthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMonths();
  }

  getMonths(): void {
    this.monthService.getMonths()
    .subscribe(months => this.months = months);
  }

}
```

At that point the month.date.getFullYear() line in the html throws this exception:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: month_r1.date.getFullYear is not a function
    at CurrentMonthComponent_a_3_Template (current-month.component.html:6)
```

Why does it no longer understand that date is a Date object when retrieving it from the server? Shouldn't the getMonths() method return a Month[] which defines date as a Date? Or does it have to do with the rxjs-observables? Here's my month.ts interface for reference. Thanks!

```
export interface Month {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    date: Date;
    topics: Array<Topic>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, it pointed me in the right direction to realize that my date was not being saved as a **Date** but rather a string that would then have to be converted back to a **Date**.

What finally worked and allowed me to call getFullYear() in that h4 tag was adding this map to the .pipe() in my http get method

```
map(months => months.map(month => ({...month, date: new Date(month.date)}))),
```

That changed it back to a **Date** object I was able to call getFullYear() on.

Answer (score 2):

I think date property is just a type of **Date** and not the actual **Date** object.

**Either** while assign date to **this.months** array, you need to convert BE response to actual **Date** object then your piece of code will work

**OR**

```
<h4>{{month.name + (new Date(month.date)).getFullYear()}}</h4>
```

Comment: I think you're right about the property being just a type of Date when I'm retrieving it from the server. However, the code you provided appears to be illegal as it caused this compiler error: ```Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Date' at column 18 in [{{month.name + new Date(month.date).getFullYear()}}] ```

Comment: I attempted the other thing you suggested by assigning date to the this.months array like so : ```for (let i = 0; i < this.months.length; i++) {
      this.months[i].date = new Date(this.months[i].date);
    }``` However, that also didn't work because apparently this.months is 'undefined'

Comment: Time being just remove `month.name` from the braces and see if that prints dates. It should work. If that works put name and date in separate braces as we are trying to append an object with string....

Comment: I think first try this `{{month.name + (new Date(month.date)).getFullYear()}}</h4>`

Comment: If nothing works, last option `{{month.name + ((new Date(month.date)).getFullYear()).toString()}}</h4>`

Comment: I'm afraid none of those codes appear to be legal within the html- they all caused compiler errors. I managed to do the same thing as getFullYear() by simply doing ```<h4>{{month.name + month.date.slice(0, 4)}}</h4>``` which gets the full year (and will do so until the year 10,000, or I suppose after the year 999 as well lol.) It apparently treats date as a string when you return it from the database.

Comment: Obviously this is not ideal. But it's the only thing i can think of for now. Your advice that it's no longer a Date was helpful, thanks.

Comment: This is ideal solution. I had made a mistake in answer. I had updated the answer as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219346/discussion-between-amdorsey12-and-micronyks).